# building website with AMP

Tags: web, google-amp

is it okay to build website completely using only AMP?
what will happen to the desktop version of the site?

does the code will be converted to normal html tag when viewer view the normal web page?

Comment: AMP is a set of best practices (in addition to some precaching provided by Google). It would be perfectly reasonable to serve a page with AMP enhancements on it to a desktop user

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build your website using only AMP. Essentially, you'll be using AMP as a framework. The company I work for has the entire site (minus 3 pages) done using AMP as a framework: https://www.craigattachments.com/.

Depending on the size of your site, a few considerations you might want to make...

- Templating is your friend. Create an overall CSS file for universal styles, and then template oriented styles based on your different page layouts.
- If you're using a universal header.php file that will apply to all pages, you can use some if statements to filter out unnecessary CSS to avoid hitting the CSS limitation set by AMP. This also works for AMP libraries you may be using on one page but not another.

For our implementation we run about 9 different CSS files that we include into the  tag using a PHP include_once and filter in and out of the header using an if statement based on which page template is being used - our site is built on Wordpress.

Have a look at the [AMP Start](https://www.ampstart.com/) page. They have some responsive page examples there.

Comment: It will work just fine on both desktop and mobile. Some people choose to split it up so they have separate sites for desktop and mobile as they may have a feature on their desktop site they don't want to lose that's not possible within the scope of AMP. If you can work within that scope, utilizing AMP as a framework is perfectly fine. Easier to maintain as well since you don't have to worry about a desktop and mobile version.